# Using ProcessBuilder to run executable from Java

Tags: java, linux, file-io

I have an executable called fingerVerification_fdu03 in my current directory. I want to run that executable from Java using the ProcessBuilder, so I do:

```
    Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("fingerVerification_fdu03").start();
```

However it is saying that it cannot find the file, even though it is in the same directory as the java program. Normally, I can execute the execute fingerVerification_fdu03 through the linux terminal simply doing:

```
./fingerVerification_fdu03
```

and it will run. What am I doing wrong?

Update:

I tried adding the directory, but still getting the same issue. I did:

```
    String workingDirectory = new String(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File tempDir = new File(workingDirectory);  
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder("fingerVerification_fdu03").
    directory(new File(workingDirectory+"//")).start();
```

Could there be something wrong with the extension of the fingerVerification_fdu03 file? I'm not sure how to find out what extension it has. It is a binary file and is not listing it's extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute the command in your prompt by specifying the current directory, since (most likely) your `PATH` doesn't reflect that directory.

You should consequently set the `PATH` (directly or indirectly) in your `ProcessBuilder` invocation. e.g. you can modify the PATH in the environment map returned by the `environment()` method, or you can amend the executable name to reflect the absolute or relative directory path (as you're doing on the command line)

Note that having the executable in the same dir as your Java program won't mean that you'll be able to execute it without specifying the directory somehow. `PATH` doesn't contain the current directory (`.`) by default, and there's an argument that it shouldn't, for security reasons.

Comment: Or just specify an absolute path for the executable.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant by amending the PATH explicitly or implicitly. Answer expanded above

Comment: Do I need to specify the directory even if I am running it from the same on that the java program is being run from?

Comment: PATH won't normally contain the current directory (.) so yes

Comment: I'm still getting the issue when I add a directory. Cannot run program "fingerVerification_fdu03" (in directory "/home/dmitry/Documents/fdx_sdk_pro_linux_arm_3_7_1_rev570/sgfplibtest"). It is listing the correct directory the file is in. I'm thinking there is something wrong with the extension I'm using?

Comment: Nvm I fixed it by updating the PATH to my current directory. Seems to be all good now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two known possibilities that could generate a FileNotFoundException , first one is that the file is realy not found in the specified folder , so try to ensure that you execute your java program from the correct folder or give the absolute path of your executable.second possibility is a problem of permission , so check that you execute your java program with a user that have the valid permission .